# i want to change the actual city field in res.partner adress to a many2one field without adding new field

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

My code looks like :

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models,fields, api

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    city_id = fields.Many2one('res.city','Ville',stored = True 
                               ,ondelete='restrict')

class ResCity(models.Model):
    _name = "res.city"
    _description = "Ville"

    name = fields.Char(u"Nom",required = True)
    state_id = fields.Many2one("res.country.state", 'Zone',ondelete='restrict')
```

so after i've add the view  in xml but my request is that i need to change the actual field without adding a new one 
the old : city = fields.char the new should look like : city = fields.many2one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override the old API defined `city` field in old API:

```py
from openerp import models,fields, api
from openerp.osv import fields as ofields

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    _columns = {
        'city': ofields.many2one('res.city', 'Ville', ondelete='restrict'),
    }
```

Have in mind, that lot of views won't work anymore, for example the partner kanban view.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the definition but it will ruin every model or view that uses this field, instead you can make it a function field:

```py
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    city_id = fields.Many2one('res.city','Ville' 
                               ,ondelete='restrict')
    @api.depends('city_id')
    @api.multi
    def set_city(self):
         self.city=self.city_id.name

    city = fields.Char(compute=set_city, store=True)
```

in your form views you should use add `city_id` and hide `city`, leave the rest in peace...

**EDIT** 
You can use the new addon `res_partner_city` which is shipped with Odoo.